# Passing avatar link into vue js component but failed

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am new in vue js.
Currently i am trying to passing data into vue js components.
So far if i passing user name or other information is working fine. But if i passing the avatar link it will showing error in npm run watch. Any solution for this?

This is my code

```
<li v-for="comment in comments">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="{{ comment.user.avatar }}" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="comment-content"><div class="arrow-comment"></div>
                <div class="comment-by">{{ comment.user.name }}<span class="date">22 August 2017</span>
                    <a href="#" class="reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
                </div>
                <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
```

[image]

This is the object i get.

Comment: It looks like the `avatar` property is not reactive. How are you setting it?

Comment: Also, in Vue 2 you cannot use interpolation in attributes like this: `src="{{ comment.user.avatar }}"`. It should be `:src="comment.user.avatar"`.

Comment: i am using storage:link to make it more secure. Btw `:src="comment.user.avatar"` is work correctly, thank for help.